# Struggling with SwiftUI to implement a global notification view

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to implement a view that can be shown on top of the navigation bar. Let's call this view the `NotificationView`. From any other SwiftUI view it should be easy to trigger this view. For example on the login view, if the username and password is wrong.

Below you'll find the code that I have so far. The problem of this code only gets visible if you enter a value into the `Username` and `Password` field. The notification view is showing up correctly, but at the same time the `Username` and `Password` fields are loosing their values.

This happens because the whole view tree is being rendered again, creating a whole new `LoginView` instance with an empty `LoginModel` via the `NavigationLink`.

How do you do this right in SwiftUI so the values are not lost?

```swift
import SwiftUI

final class NotificationModel: ObservableObject {
    func show(text: String) {
        self.text = text
        isHidden = false
    }

    @Published
    var isHidden = true
    var text = ""
}

struct NotificationView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject
    var model: NotificationModel

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            if !self.model.isHidden {
                Group {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.triangle")
                            .font(Font.largeTitle.weight(.light))
                        Text(self.model.text)
                            .font(Font.body.weight(.medium))
                            .padding()
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: geometry.safeAreaInsets.top + 44)
                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: geometry.safeAreaInsets.top, leading: 20, bottom: 0, trailing: 20))
                }
                .background(Color.red)
                .transition(AnyTransition.move(edge: .top).combined(with: .opacity))
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation {
                        self.model.isHidden = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }

}

final class LoginModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published
    var email = ""

    @Published
    var password = ""

    let notificationModel: NotificationModel

    init(notificationModel: NotificationModel) {
        self.notificationModel = notificationModel
    }

    func submit() {
        notificationModel.show(text: "Username/password wrong")
    }
}

struct LoginView: View {
    @ObservedObject
    var model: LoginModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Username", text: $model.email)
            Divider()
            TextField("Password", text: $model.password)
            Divider()
            Button(action: {
                self.model.submit()
            }) {
                Text("Submit")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject
    var notificationModel: NotificationModel

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    NavigationLink(destination: LoginView(model: LoginModel(notificationModel: notificationModel))) {
                        Text("Login")
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Start")
            }
            NotificationView()
        }
    }
}
```

[image: simulator video]

Answer (score 0):

You may need to flip LoginModel and notificationModel in the contentView.

```
            final class NotificationModel: ObservableObject {
                func show(text: String) {
                    self.text = text
                    self.isHidden = false
                }

                @Published
                var isHidden = true
                var text = ""
            }

            struct NotificationView: View {
                @EnvironmentObject
                var model: NotificationModel

                var body: some View {
                    GeometryReader { geometry in
                        if !self.model.isHidden {
                            Group {
                                HStack {
                                    Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.triangle")
                                        .font(Font.largeTitle.weight(.light))
                                    Text(self.model.text)
                                        .font(Font.body.weight(.medium))
                                        .padding()
                                    Spacer()
                                }
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: geometry.safeAreaInsets.top + 44)
                                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: geometry.safeAreaInsets.top, leading: 20, bottom: 0, trailing: 20))
                            }
                            .background(Color.red)
                            .transition(AnyTransition.move(edge: .top).combined(with: .opacity))
                            .onTapGesture {
                                withAnimation {
                                    self.model.isHidden = true
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                }

            }

            final class LoginModel: ObservableObject {
                @Published
                var email = ""

                @Published
                var password = ""



                let notificationModel: NotificationModel

                init(notificationModel: NotificationModel) {
                    self.notificationModel = notificationModel
                }

                func submit() {
                    notificationModel.show(text: "Username/password wrong")
                }
            }

            struct LoginView: View {
                @ObservedObject
                var model: LoginModel

                var body: some View {
                    VStack {
                        TextField("Username", text: $model.email)
                        Divider()
                        TextField("Password", text: $model.password)
                        Divider()
                        Button(action: {
                            self.model.submit()
                        }) {
                            Text("Submit")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            struct ContentView: View {
                @EnvironmentObject  var loginModel : LoginModel

                var body: some View {




                  return  ZStack {
                        NavigationView {
                            VStack {
                                NavigationLink(destination: LoginView(model: loginModel)) {
                                    Text("Login")
                                }
                                Spacer()
                            }
                            .navigationBarTitle("Start")
                        }
                    NotificationView().environmentObject(loginModel.notificationModel)
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is not really an option. Imagine there was another set of nested views (tab bar etc), that represent the logged in part of the app. The problem would be the same, and I wouldn't want to have the outer most view holding the models for the inner most ones.

Comment: Each login model or intermediate view model should have its own notification mode. There is no global notification model